# Bootstrap 3 modal pattern with Ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Here is what I'm trying to base my code on (based on Bootstrap ~2):

http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/tK3rX/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Boostrap modal sample</h1>    
    <a {{action showModal}} href="#">Open modal</a>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modal">
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{view.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>{{view.content}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" {{action close target="view"}} class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
</script>
```

And this is my jsfiddle with Bootstrap 3:

http://jsfiddle.net/5R8U9/9/

Could anyone help me find the problem with my fiddle?

Comment: Could you please describe your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with css:

In your `ModelView` you have `classNames: ["modal", "fade", "hide"],`. You must remove the `hide` class.

In the template you have another problem. Your are using the `modal` and `fade` again. Since you have specified it already in `ModelView`, this is unnecessary.

Template

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Becaues when the view is created the result will be 2 `modal` classes and the layout will be broken:

```
<div class="modal fade ember-view" >
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

The final result is this http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/rrXc2/

Comment: So what is the correlation between html classes and the classes property in Ember.view? This is still not very clear to me.

Comment: When you create a Ember.View instance. It top element by default is a div, without class, and a generated id. By example: <div id="ember324" >... some content of template ...</div>. To override this you can use tagName, classNames, and elementId. In your case you informed both the boostrap modal classes in the Ember.View, and the template, so the options to correct this is: remove the clases from Ember.View, and leave in template, or the opposite, like I have done, remove from template, and set in classNames.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Bootstrap 3 and Ember 1.0, in your route you should replace

```
App.ModalView.create({ title: "My title", content: "My content" }).append();
```

with

```
this.container.lookup('view:modal').append();
```

in order to avoid the defaultContainer deprecation (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2597)

Comment: how to pass those parameters (title, content) into the view now?

Comment: To pass parameters you can do the following:  var v = this.container.lookup('view:modal');  v.set('title',"my title"); v.set('content', "my content"); v.appendTo(App.rootElement);