# Rendering a form inside a bootstrap modal in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

There are plenty of questions already that ask about modals in Ember (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396994/modal-popup-with-ember-1-0-rc6) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381298/bootstrap-3-modal-pattern-with-ember-js)). Even the [cookbook has an article](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/) that explains how to use modals, but none of these cover form submissions that require validation from the server within the modal (ie, username already taken).

Following along with the cookbook, I have a named outlet in my application template.

```
{{outlet}}
{{outlet modal}}
```

And an action that triggers rendering a template inside the modal outlet (using bootstrap).

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  actions:
    openModal: (template, model) ->
      @controllerFor(template).set('model', model)
      @render template, into: 'application', outlet: 'modal'

    closeModal: ->
      @render '', into: 'application', outlet: 'modal'
```

Obviously I'm calling this action from within a link.

```
<a href="#" {{action openModal "person.edit" model}}>Edit</a>
```

Where `model` is the model of the current route.

In the `PesonEditView` I hook into the `didInsertElement` function to enable the bootstrap modal. Inside this hook, I also listen to the `hidden.bs.modal` event fired by bootstrap when the close button is clicked to clear out the modal outlet.

```
App.PersonEditView = Ember.View.extend

  didInsertElement: ->
    @$('.modal').modal('show').on 'hidden.bs.modal', =>
      @get('controller').send('closeModal')
```

My question is, how can I define a `save` action that will close the modal (using bootstraps animations) *after* it has validated on the server? The sequence of events that I see are required are, 1) `save` gets triggered on controller, 2) if successful save, close the modal (which would require calling `@$('.modal').modal('hide')` from the view).

I'm not sure what Ember experts would suggest here, since it seems as though the view and controller will need to communicate very closely.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

In response to edpaez's comment, I have tried resolving the promise returned by `save` from within the view. For example, in my template

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" {{action "save" target="view"}}>Save</button>
```

The view

```
App.PersonEditView = Ember.View.extend
  actions:
    save: ->
      @get('controller').send('save').then(@closeModal.bind(@))

  closeModal: ->
    @$('.modal').modal('hide')

  # the rest omitted for brevity
```

And the controller

```
App.PersonEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    save: ->
      @get('model').save()
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined
```

Comment: Have you considered targeting the `save` action to the view, calling  a `save` **method** in the controller which returns a promise that resolves when the `save` in the model resolves? The controller would abstract the model-saving logic and the view would get notified when the promise resolves.

Comment: Return values of action handlers are used for bubbling. Also, the send method you're using returns nothing. You have to call directly the method (don't put it inside the actions hash). in view: `@get('controller').save().then...`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your help. If you write an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try targeting the `save` action to the view:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" {{action "save" target="view"}}>Save</button>
```

and call a `save` method in the controller. That method would return a promise that would resolve when the `save` method from the model resolves.

```
App.PersonEditView = Ember.View.extend
  actions:
    save: ->
      @get('controller').save().then(@closeModal.bind(@))

  closeModal: ->
    @$('.modal').modal('hide')


App.PersonEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    save: ->
      @get('model').save()
```

This way, the controller abstracts the model-saving logic and the view gets notified when the model saves so it can behave as expected.

Make sure you call the `save` method in the controller instead of sending an action. the `send` method returns nothing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Any idea how to wrap this modal functionality into a component so I can reuse it for the edit route? You can only specify actions to send from the component (ie, `{{my-component save="save" ...}}`) and use `sendAction()` in the component. I can't call methods on a controller directly.

Comment: Wrap `closeModal` in a promise and send it with `sendAction`. Then if save succeeds you can resolve the promise and hide the modal. If `save` fails (for example form validation) then you can reject the promise. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20810854/306503