# Return a promise from a controller action in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a component that needs to communicate with a controller and eventually perform some clean up *after* the controller says everything is ok (ie, jQuery "un"-initialization). I think the best way to accomplish this is with a promise so that the component can clean up after the controller completes its task. But how can a controller action return a promise? Alternatively, can a component call a dynamic method directly on a controller?

For example, lets say I have a `ModalDialogComponent`.

```
App.ModalDialogComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  didInsertElement: -> 
    @$('.modal').modal('show')

  actions:
    save: ->
      @sendAction('save').then(@closeModal.bind(@))

    # some other actions are omitted

  closeModal: ->
    @$('.modal').modal('hide')
```

And I can instantiate the component inside a template named `foo`,

```
{{modal-form save="save" ...}}
```

And implement the `save` method on FooController

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  save: ->
    # how can we tell the component that this was successful?
```

As you can see, I only want the `closeModal` function to execute if the `save` action was successful. In other words, only close the modal if the record was saved successfully.

Is this possible, or am I going about it completely wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`send` and `sendAction` are one way streets, that being said, you can send a defer to the action and expect it to resolve/reject it.

```
var defer = Ember.RSVP.defer();

defer.promise.then(function(resolvedValue){
  alert(resolvedValue); 
});

setTimeout(function(){
  defer.resolve('hello world');
},2000);
```

Yours would look a bit like this

```
var defer = Ember.RSVP.defer(),
    self = this;

defer.promise.then(function(){
  self.closeModal();
},
function(){
  alert('error');
});

this.sendAction('save', defer);
```

save action

```
actions: {
  save: function(defer){

    // if succeeded 
    defer.resolve();

    // or if failure occurs 
    defer.reject();
  }
}
```

Be careful, you want to make sure you don't leave out the reject route, you'd hate to have the modal stuck up there because the save failed and there wasn't a failure method.

Sorry I didn't convert to coffee script, I figure you'll either understand or convert and understand and I won't have given you a wrong answer.

Comment: No problem for the CoffeeScript. Thanks :)

Comment: Pass a promise to sendAction... You're a genius!

Comment: Rawr, the feeling is mutual ;)

Comment: Nice and easy to understand, thanks! Will use and re-use.