# Ember: How to execute a promise after this.send()

Tags: ember.js

How do I do something like:

```
this.send('someFunction').then(function(response) {
   // do something with the response data
});
```

In this case, "someFunction" is an action from a mixin.

Answer (score 3):

send doesn't return anything, but you can send a defer/promise into it and expect the action to resolve it.

I'll find the example I gave a few weeks back and put it up here.

[Return a promise from a controller action in Ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810162/return-a-promise-from-a-controller-action-in-ember/20810854#20810854)