# How to reload ember model within a computed property

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have two question about computed properties within `Ember Controller`.

- How can i reload a model?
- How can i return a promise?

that is from a computed property within an `Ember Controller`.

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    poll: function() {
        // Question 1
        // reload the model from server (send GET /stuff).
        return this.get('model.poll');
    }.property('model');


    second: function() {
        // Question 2
        // return a promise 
        return this.find('choices');
    }.property('model');
});
```

**Edit**

I've setup a jsbin that uses an [online fake rest server](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder), but i couldn't get it working, i would appreciate any help. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EnOqUxe/155/edit

**Edit2**

Ok your jsbin works, I've tried the same on my pc and ember inspector promise tab shows a pending request any idea why?:

```
DS:RestAdapter#ajax GET /api/v1/games/1 Pending

VM409:161
2
Ember Inspector (Promise Trace): DS: RESTAdapter#ajax GET to /api/v1/games/1
    at new Promise (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember/ember.js:10173:9)
    at __exports__.default.Adapter.extend.ajax (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data.js:1828:16)
    at __exports__.default.Adapter.extend.find (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data.js:1347:21)
    at _find (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data.js:11883:29)
    at Ember.Object.extend.fetchRecord (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data.js:10504:23)
    at _fetchRecord (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data.js:10553:53)
    at Ember.Object.extend._flushPendingFetchForType (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember-data/ember-data.js:10590:11)
    at http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember/ember.js:4536:20
    at Object.OrderedSet.forEach (http://192.168.56.101:3000/public/assets/scripts/lib/ember/ember.js:4379:14) VM409:164
```

Comment: Are you using `ember-data` (`DS.Model`), `ember-model`, ..?

Comment: Maybe this can help you with the promise part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810162/return-a-promise-from-a-controller-action-in-ember

Comment: @louscoquio yes i am using ember-data#canary and DS.Model

Comment: @KarolineBrynildsen my controller action initiate the promise rather than resolve it so that doesn't help.

Comment: You would basically do return this.get('model').reload() and that should return you a promise. More here http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha I've tried that method but it doesn't do anything. Can you put a jsbin? Can i return that promise inside the controller method, so it works?

Comment: Its kinda difficult to put things up in jsbin, since reload makes a call to server to get the updated data(too lazy to set up server side of things). You can look into your console logs to check if it actually making a get rest api call when you call reload on the model. If thats happening, atleast one part of your problem is solved, if you could explain your problem better we can work out on a solution. I really couldnt understand what poll and second properites are trying to do.

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha There is an online fake rest server you can use, see my edit. Please demonstrate model reload even the server doesn't work, when i do model.reload() it basically does nothing.

Comment: Here is a demo of reload : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qatizimohowi/1/. I need to add the serializer because the json is not exactly in a format that ember data expects it to be.

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha it is stuck on pending request on my server, see my edit please. what can cause that? thanks for your time.

Comment: humm not sure what's going on there but can you check if your get request to "/api/v1/games/1" is getting resolved. Check it in your browser console, seems like as if your server is not responding or atleast taking a lot of time.

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha no it doesn't show up in the network tab, so no server is involved.