# Ember-CLI upgrade causing error with application route promise resolution

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've just upgraded from ember-cli 0.0.42 to 0.0.44 and now I am getting an error with my model hook on my application route

`Error while processing route: profile.index undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Ember.Mixin.create.extractSingle (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63379:25)
    at apply (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32449:27)
    at superWrapper [as extractSingle] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32024:15)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extractFind (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:65641:21)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:65526:37)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73793:34
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:59657:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:59669:17)
    at publish (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:59640:11)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:42159:9`

I have no clue how this is related to ember-cli, but if I am on 0.0.42 there is no problem.

My application route:

```
model: function() {
  var preloadedUser = window.PreloadStore.get('currentUser');

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      currentUser: this.store.find('user-profile', preloadedUser.id)
  });
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.controllerFor('currentUser').set('model', model.currentUser);
}
```

Any promise returned in the application route seems to cause the error. An object literal does not trigger the error and all sub-routes work just fine with promises.

```
Ember      : 1.8.0-beta.1 vendor.js:28327
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a
```

I am using the RESTAdapter and the payload back is:

```
{"userProfiles":{"id":"d1bdd26a-25b9-40d4-a166-4ec2e66bee70","prefix":null,"first":"Ryan","middle":null,"last":"Hirsch","manager":null}}
```

Any thoughts or ideas why promise application route resolution is erroring?

Comment: What's the json coming back from the `user-profile` call?  Which adapter are you using?

Comment: And serializer also, if you are using a custom serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Your payload is not exactly in a format that ember data expects it to be. You need to add a serializer, something like this.

```
DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id) {
    var profiles = payload;

    payload = { userProfiles: [payload] };
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id);
  },
});
```

I am not sure about the exact format, customize it to fix it.

Comment: I am using the same version of ember regardless of the ember-cli version. I have also tried 'going back' to ember 1.7.0 and it still doesn't help.

Comment: I thought the json api spec states single items are to be returned as `{ items: { /* item data */ }}` is that not accurate?

Comment: @RyanHirsch I am not sure about the format, but stack trace suggest that error occurs in this method `extractSingle`. Put a breakpoint there, and trace the expected format. Probably it needs to be an array such as `{items: [ { //... }, { // ... } ] }`. See the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282920/how-to-reload-ember-model-within-a-computed-property) for some formatting help.