# How to handle error/event when the Ember-Data Store do not find any record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The situation is:

- The session.userID has a proper ID
- However, there is no user data in the backend database (Firebase)

Here is the code:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    if (this.session.userID) {
      return this.store.find('user', this.session.userID).then(function(_user) {
        console.log('user found', _user);
        return _user;
      }, function(error) {
        // user does not exist or some other error
        console.log('Application Model did not find user in Firebase');
        return null;
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Application Model did not find any session.userID');
      return null;
    }
  },

});
```

**My expectation:** The Promisse should call the error function:

```
function(error) {
  // user does not exist or some other error
  console.log('Application Model did not find user in Firebase');     
});
```

**The error:** However, I get the following error:

```
    Error: no record was found at https://dynamicslife.firebaseio.com/users/facebook%3A931321683548734
        at https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/emberfire/1.2.7/emberfire.min.js:10:3400
        at c (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:17:65)
        at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:123:689
        at uc (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:50:20)
        at Xe (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:123:675)
        at Ve.Vb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:123:617)
        at Ye.Vb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:124:418)
        at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:139:409
        at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:68:878
        at pc (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.2/firebase.js:62:618) ember.js:14876
    Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: no record was found at https://dynamicslife.firebaseio.com/users/facebook%3A931321683548734
```

**Question:** I know that there is no record to be found. But how to handle this situation and avoid being throw an error? I was under the impression that the Promise would allow me to manage the error before the system crash.

Comment: What's the response from server look like, with what http code?

Comment: Kingpin2k, I'm so glad of your dedication to help the Ember community. Big THANK YOU! I edited my question to give more details on the error.

Comment: Looking at this, I'm tempted to say it's an error in the emberfire implementation.  When dealing with a promise you either need to call the resolve or reject callback.  It's possible they failed to implement calling the reject callback on certain errors.  So that promise is stuck in limbo, never being properly rejected.

Comment: Looking at the implementation, it looks like it should be calling the reject path, but your saying it doesn't hit `console.log('Application Model did not find user in Firebase');`, right?

Comment: You are right, the application doesn't hit the `console.log('Application Model did not find user in Firebase');` nor the `console.log('user found', _user);`. From you comment, I'm wondering if I could wrap the `this.store.find('user', this.session.userID)` into a RSVP.Promise to handle the error. You provided an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810162/return-a-promise-from-a-controller-action-in-ember/20810854#20810854

Comment: The weird thing is, their find statement already is wrapped in a promise

Answer (score 1):

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    if (this.session.userID) {
      return this.store.find('user', this.session.userID);
    } else {
      console.log('Application Model did not find any session.userID');
      return null;
    }
  },
  afterModel: function(user, transition) {
    if (user.get('length') === 0) {
      console.log('fail');
    } else {
      console.log('success');
    }
  }
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel

Comment: The EmberFire adapter does not seems to handle the find() method properly. My application was crashing at the model and did not run the afterModel.

Comment: You are sure that this.session.userId is valid?

Comment: Yes, it is. I can see it in the Chrome Dev. Tool with the proper userID.

Comment: The problem is not here. As you can see in the docs this approach is completely correct and even recommended.

Comment: I agree. For the moment, I have been able use findById as a workaround. Once I find what is the issue, I will update this question.